# Is it possible to instantiate a PG::Connection while running a ruby on rails rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is some of the rspec code that I have

```
before do
  FactoryBot.create(:user, first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
end

let(:conn) do
  PG::Connection.connect(
    'localhost', # host
    5432,        # port
    nil,         # options
    nil,         # tty
    'test',   # db name
    'postgres',  # username
    'password'    # password
  )
end

it 'works' do
  result = subject
  connection_config = User.connection_db_config
  puts connection_config
  require 'pry'
  binding.pry
end
```

Things I've tried:

- User.connection_db_config to find connection info

  => #<ActiveRecord::DatabaseConfigurations::UrlConfig:0x000000010536fac8
  @configuration_hash={:adapter=>"postgresql", :encoding=>"utf8", :pool=>100, :prepared_statements=>false, :database=>"test", :url=>nil},
  @env_name="test",
  @name="primary",
  @url=nil>

  - nothing useful about if my connection params may be incorrect
- During binding.pry, I can verify `User.last` returns the user that was created by FactoryBot but when I use the conn.exec_params("select * from users"), I see 0 rows
- checked my local dbs while the test was paused by binding.pry and did not see the inserted User row either
- within database.yml I define the db configuration using a url but when printing `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` during the pry breakpoint, the value is nil

```
    test:
        <<: *default
        url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
        database: test
```

Is it possible to connect to the same DB FactoryBot is inserting to using a connection created through PG::Connection?

For context, I am porting over a very old script and would prefer to minimize refactoring if possible.

Comment: Whats the actual underlying problem that you're trying to solve here? I don't think you actually need any of this. `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` is automatically merged with and takes preceedence over the settings from `database.yml`. If you want to get a connection you would do it with `User.connection` which gets the per model database connection. You can also get it from `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`

Comment: I mean yes it's very much possible to manually connect in a test or wherever you want to. But do you really need it?

Comment: I'll admit this is a special case, in most cases I don't need to. In this case, I need to connect to a read only follower DB in production instead of the main DB but I'd like to add unit tests to this old script that leverage code used for the main DB. I know there are ways to set up multiple connections in rails but the risk is larger than I'm comfortable with so if I can manually connect to the test db to write these unit tests, that would be amazing.

Comment: Hopefully that answers your question @max, to sum up, I'm dealing with old code being put into a monolith where it would be risky to refactor the monolith to accommodate the old code